# Importing a module based on installed python version?

Tags: python, json

My module currently imports the `json` module, which is only available in 2.6. I'd like to make a check against the python version to import `simplejson`, which can be built for 2.5 (and is the module adopted in 2.6 anyway). Something like:

```
if __version__ 2.5:
    import simplejson as json
else:
    import json
```

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

of course, it doesn't work around cases when in python-2.5 you don't have `simplejson` installed, the same as your example.

Comment: might wanna do "import simplejson as json" though... but yeah, much better than checking python version

Comment: fixed before I saw your comment

Answer (score 19):

Though the ImportError approach (SilentGhost's answer) is definitely best for this example, anyone wanting to do that `__version__` thing would use something like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 6):
    import simplejson as json
else:
    import json
```

To be absolutely clear though, this is *not* the "best way" to do what you wanted... it's merely the correct way to do what you were trying to show with `__version__`.

Comment: the other way around, simplejson is available in py2.5

Comment: Thanks for the correction... I meant >= and not <.  Feel free to delete your comment and mine (or I'll do mine if you can't).

Comment: if version is higher then (2,6) there is **no** simplejson available!

Comment: Doh!  I didn't see that you'd already edited it, and just reversed it without thinking, undoing your change.  Changed again, and fixed minor typo.

Comment: would this be the way for determining python 2 vs 3?  Some import thats not part of standard library has to be modified for python 3, but its not until a method is used that an error would occur.  So in a local file directory there would be something like; pyread2 and pyread3.

Answer (score 2):

You can import one or more modules without Handling ImportError error:

```
import sys

major_version = sys.version_info.major
if major_version == 2:
    import SocketServer
    import SimpleHTTPServer
    import urllib2
elif major_version == 3:
    import http.server as SimpleHTTPServer
    import socketserver as SocketServer
    import urllib.request as urllib2
```